# A suitable text editor for C that includes lint & cstyle?

Tags: c, linux, ide, coding-style, lint

I'd like to use a nice C code-editor, that would have built-in support for:

1. Code-colouring for C, Make, XML, Java, etc.
2. Lint
3. Cstyle
4. Works under Ubuntu
5. Possibly a nice visual debugger integrated, too?

I'd rather not use an IDE, as most of them seem to me somewhat clumsy with C.

I am a former Java dev, so I'm sorry if I sound boring to some.

Thanks guys!

Comment: emacs?  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryProgramming

Comment: Bash is a nice IDE for C. It works with any editor and it also does Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using VIM. VIM has a high learning curve in the beginning but it's excellent once you are highly acquainted with it. VIM also has many excellent plugins like NERD-Tree and Command-T which allows you to search for file names in your directory tree with just a couple keystrokes. VIM is also fast with many nice built in functionalities and it requires minimized computer resource so it's very fast on most computer (works real well for computers with limited resources). VIM also has syntax highlight and formatting for almost all the languages that you can name. It can be a standalone editor or you can equip it with enough plugins to make it the fastest IDE ever built. Good luck with your choices :)

Comment: Thanks. Looks a bit nerdy for me somehow. I mean it really is a bit hard to work with.

Comment: If you are used to this nerdy interface, you'll never use other IDE :)

Comment: Wow, and you seem to be a ruby man! How odd. I love Rubymine for writing rails apps.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs will probably do, but it might be cumbersome to adjust everything to your needs and to get used to it.

Emacs comes bundled with C, Java, XML, Make, and support for other languages. Almost every language can be plugged in and is already plugged in by someone else.

Works of course under Ubuntu and integrates well with GDB.